# Compare large number of values in several datasets

Tags: python, json, loops

I am working on a project that will require iterating and comparing a large number of values in a large number of datasets. Sample code below - shows my thinking for just 2 datasets - and it is a little slow. I would like to know if there is a better pattern for doing this type of comparison that I should be using. My code below shows 2 sets of data, but imagine there are 10 sets, and I need to iterate and compare ask of dataset 1 to bid of dataset 2, then ask of dataset 2 and bid of dataset 1. Now complicate that with 10 datasets not 2. This is why I would like some advice on the best pattern for this.

```
j1 = json.loads(r1) # json response contains MANY values for ASKS and BIDS
j2 = json.loads(r2) # json response, contains MANY values for ASKS and BIDS
for ask, aval in j1['eth_btc']['asks']:
    for bid, bval in j2['eth_btc']['bids']:
        if ask < bid:
            if aval <= bval:
              # do some stuff!
# now do the reverse - ASK from J2 and BID from J1
for ask, aval in j2['eth_btc']['asks']:
    for bid, bval in j1['eth_btc']['bids']:
        if ask < bid:
            if aval <= bval:
              # do some different stuff!
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Could you load your files into Pandas DataFrames?

Comment: I generally approach these problems using set theory and would use pandas data frames or database tables.  You could perhaps use the set datatype also.  Try to vectorise to avoid loops.

Comment: Just full disclosure - here is a tiny subset of what the data looks like:r1 = """{
    "eth_btc":{
        "asks":[
            [105.426,0.01],
            [105.5,15],
            [104.504,0.425],
            [105.505,0.1]
        ],
        "bids":[
            [103.2,2.48502251],
            [103.082,0.46540304],
            [104.91,0.99007913],
            [102.83,0.07832332]
        ]
    }
}""" I have never used Pandas but have heard of it. Is there a particular set of Pandas functions you think would be best suited to this type of comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I have continued to investigate this and have come across a method (I didn't bother to update the variable names to be brief):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for x, y in zip_longest(xpts, ypts):
    print(x,y)
```

This has provided a huge performance improvement for me. If anyone has an idea of another pattern that would be more efficient please let me know.